# Create a SSH connection through a proxy

Tags: go

I need to etablish an SSH connection over a HTTP proxy, and I don't find anyway to do it.

In pseudo code, it might be something like this:

```
import (
"net"
"golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

proxyConn, _: = net.Dial("tcp", proxyURL)
conn, _: = proxyConn.Dial("tcp", serverURL)
c, chans, reqs, err: = ssh.NewClientConn(conn, serverURL, & sshConfig)
client: = ssh.NewClient(c, chans, reqs)
```

Steps:

- Connect to the http proxy
- Using the "proxy connection" to etablish the SSH connection
- Maybe we can achieve that with the currect package but I don't find anyway to do it

Comment: You can set up a socks5 proxy over a http proxy (many options) and use a socks5 dialer with your ssh library. Socks5 is much more widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to proxy an ssh connection through an HTTP proxy you need to find an ssh library in Go that will support proxying through the http proxy using the CONNECT method.

This library seems to support it: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/blacknon/go-sshlib#Proxy.CreateHttpProxyDialer

There is also a somewhat strange example here: https://www.example-code.com/golang/ssh_http_proxy.asp

I do not think it is possible to do this with golang.org/x/crypto/ssh without somehow handling the CONNECT piece separately.

Ooh! It looks like you could use this lib https://github.com/mwitkow/go-http-dialer to connect through an http proxy and get a net.Conn, you could then use that with the ssh lib!